# How can I bind struct with array members in emscripten?

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I want to bind struct with array member.
If i write C Code like this,

```
struct positions
{
    int[2] points;
}
```

I referenced [this document](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) but I didn't find how can I bind struct with array and how to use it in Javascript code.
How Can I bind struct "positions" with member "points"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the following example:

```
struct Array10 {
    int& get(size_t index) {
        return data[index];
    }
    int data[10];
};

val Array10_get(Array10& arr, size_t index) {
    if (index < 10) {
        return val(arr.get(index));
    } else {
        return val::undefined();
    }
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(non_member_functions) {
    class_<Array10>("Array10")
        .function("get", &Array10_get)
        ;
}
```

It binds a struct which has a fixed-sized array as member and you can retrieve values with the `get` function.